# Convert month name to string number using Carbon?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When i use this code, when language is English for example for December i get `$date_number = 12`, but when i use German i get for Dezember 
`$date_number= 01`. Thats way i think that i need to use Carbon to convert month name to string number of month, so that i can use localization. Any suggestion how can i fix that?

```
$date_number = strval(date('m', strtotime($month)));

  $articles = Articles::whereRaw('MONTH(created_at) ='.$date_number)->where('approved',1)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
$articles = Articles::whereRaw('MONTH(created_at) ='.Carbon::parse('1975-05-21 22:23:00.123456')->month)->where('approved',1)->get();
```

You can try setting local to:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'German');
echo $dt->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y');

Carbon::setLocale('de');
```

Check out this link:
http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Answer (score -1):

check this code for get month using carbon
*$timestemp = "2016-4-5 05:06:01";
    $month = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestemp)->month;
dd($month);*

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's better to give an explanation as well as the code.